# How to store the ID of the object being hovered

Tags: jquery

I have this bit of code:

```
$('.div').mouseover(function() {
   alert(this.id);
});
```

This gets me the ID of the object that I'm hovering, but I'd like to store it in a variable. I'm not sure how to do this; I know this is probably overly simple, but can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly like you said: **store in a variable** :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a variable out side the event to access it afterwards. If you declare it within `mouseover` handler you wont be able to access it out side handler.

```
var somevar = '';

$('.div').mouseover(function() {
   somevar = this.id;
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `var` before defining the variable.

Comment: Thanks! How might I then target that element's children of a particular class?

Answer (score 3):

```
var id;
$('.div').mouseover(function() {
   id =  this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular var but additionally JQuery has a data function that lets you store arbitrary data within JQuery objects.

```
$('.div').mouseover(function() {
   $(this).data('objid', this.id);
});
```

To access the data:

```
$(this).data('objid');
```

More info at: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

You would declare a global variable, or via a namespace property, and then access it.

Example with a script tag (you could put this at the top of you js file also

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var globalId;

    $('.div').mouseover(function() {
        globalId = this.id;
    });
</script>
```

This is the simplest way to do it.